# webpack doesn't rebuild after i execute npm install

Tags: webpack, npm-install, rebuild

> have a demo to describe this questions

in here:
https://github.com/abnerCrack/react-storybook-demo.git
and run npm install

> questions

```
step:

normal： 

npm run storybook

in new shell

if i am  edit any file in node_modules webpack file watch it's work

but when you execute npm install range-input-react or any modules,

the webpack watch doesn't to rebuild.
```

how can i make it rebuild?

Comment: Could you give [npm-install-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-webpack-plugin) a go? If you go through that, watch just might work.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen awesome~nice job